# Figure Headings in Laboratory Reports

Tags: chromatography

How do I write a figure legend for a thin layer chromatography plate drawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide all the data that are necessary to reproduce the experiment:

- TLC material (silica gel or aluminium oxide)
- composition of the mobile phase
- special tricks, such as running the TLC in methanol first for 5 mm to squeeze the initial spot to a very narrow band
- detection of the separated bands/spots:

  - $\mathrm{R_f}$ values
  - do the spots have a colour
  - do the show fluorescence
  - which reagents did you use for staining

---

**UPDATE**

If you report on a series of measurements, it's usually good practise describe the conditions that didn't change (type of TLC plate, staining solutions, etc.) in the general section of the experimental part of the report/article/thesis.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of each spot mark your legends by alpha/numerals. Outside put the meaning of your legends. Mention solvent system used for elution.